# Firestore efficient/fast query posts a user has liked

Tags: firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I have a collection with users and a collection with posts.
In every post there is a sub collection of user ids that liked that post. Additionally I also have a sub collection in the users where I save the id of the posts that a user liked.

Now my question is, what would be the most efficient query to get all the posts a specific user liked.

The ways I know are: (examples are in Javascript)

1. Query the sub collection of a user to get all the post ids that the user liked. Than get all Documents with query and query Constraint
   The problem is I need to separate this into multiple queries because the query constraint "in" can only get up to 10 elements in the array:
   `const data = query(collection(db, "posts"), where("postId", "in", postIds))`
2. Query the sub collection of a user to get all the post ids that the user liked. Than get all Documents (posts) individually.
   So for every document I need to do this:
    `const data = await getDoc(doc(db, "posts", "postId"))`

Is there any other more efficient and faster way of achieving this.

Comment: It will be a lot easier for us to help if you show some actual sample data/documents that you're working with.

Comment: You seem to have two quite clear approaches. Did you consider testing them and measuring to see which is faster?

Comment: Subcollection vs nested objects ("maps") vs an array, for recording the users who liked the post?

Comment: Have you tried what Doug and Frank suggested? Please respond using @AlexMamo